# Accessing React state variables when they are loaded form promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, state

I have a simple component that loads in the data from a job as follows

```
export class ViewJob extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      currentJob: {},
      checkedCompleted: false,
    };

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    loadJobFromId(this.props.id)
      .then(job => this.setState({currentJob: job}))
  }
```

In my render when I try to access a nested property:

```
this.state.currentJob.selectedCompany
```

I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

This seems to be because the state of selectedCompany is first undefined and then when the promises resolves it is set.

What is the best practice for handling this in React?

Comment: You are not trying to access the property `root` in your example. But yes, on the initial render, `this.state.currentJob` is an empty object. You have to account for that in your `render` method.

Comment: I thought about doing that as a conditional (this.state.currentJob ? <Component /> : null). Are there any ways to better do that?

Comment: No, that's typically how it's done. Note though that `this.state.currentJob` is an empty object, so testing `this.state.currentJob` will be `true`. You may want to initialize it with `null`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll go ahead and do that. I was used to the async pipe in Angular2/4/5 which seemed like a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

You should render the part that's using `this.state.currentJob.selectedCompany` only once the promise is resolved. So you can try something like this:

```
export class ViewJob extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      currentJob: {},
      checkedCompleted: false,
      jobsFetched: false
    };

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    loadJobFromId(this.props.id)
      .then(job => this.setState({currentJob: job, jobsFecthed: ture}))
  }


  render(){
    { this.state.jobsFetched ? **[RENDER_WHAT_YOU_ARE_RENDERING_NOW]** : <Text>Loading...</Text> }
```

This way the component will be rendered only when the jobs are fetched/ promise resolved.

Comment: Introducing an additional state variable seems unnecessary. Just initialize `currentJob` with `null` instead.

Comment: If the component grows than this state variable can be more useful.